# Unable to merge fork of repository

Tags: git, github

There is a project on GitHub that I follow (upstream):

https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque

I have a fork of this repo (origin):

https://github.com/spudstud/torque

New branches have been added to the upstream repository that I want to pull into origin, and then to my local machine.

According to GitHub help, this should be easy. I should be able synchronise my fork with the following commands. https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

Unfortunately, the upstream branches that I want (4.2.3, 4.2.3.1,  4.2.3.h2, 4.2.3.h3), still do not appear in origin

```
git clone git@github.com:spudstud/torque.git
cd torque/
git remote add upstream https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque.git
git remote -v
      origin    git@github.com:spudstud/torque.git (fetch)
      origin    git@github.com:spudstud/torque.git (push)
      upstream    https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque.git (fetch)
      upstream    https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque.git (push)
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master

git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/2.5-dev
  remotes/origin/2.5.12
  remotes/origin/4.1-dev
  remotes/origin/4.1.0
  remotes/origin/4.1.4
  remotes/origin/4.1.4-1648
  remotes/origin/4.1.5
  remotes/origin/4.1.5.1
  remotes/origin/4.1.5.2
  remotes/origin/4.2.0
  remotes/origin/4.2.1
  remotes/origin/4.2.2
  **** 4.2.3,  4.2.3.1,  4.2.3.h2,  4.2.3.h3 should show up about here^ ****
  ...
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/2.5-dev
  remotes/upstream/2.5.12
  remotes/upstream/4.1-dev
  remotes/upstream/4.1.0
  remotes/upstream/4.1.4
  remotes/upstream/4.1.4-1648
  remotes/upstream/4.1.5
  remotes/upstream/4.1.5.1
  remotes/upstream/4.1.6
  remotes/upstream/4.1.6.h1
  remotes/upstream/4.1.6.h2
  remotes/upstream/4.2-dev
  remotes/upstream/4.2.0
  remotes/upstream/4.2.1
  remotes/upstream/4.2.2
  remotes/upstream/4.2.2.ufl
  remotes/upstream/4.2.3
  remotes/upstream/4.2.3.1
  remotes/upstream/4.2.3.h2
  remotes/upstream/4.2.3.h3
  remotes/upstream/master
```

Nothing I have read so far can explain what the issue might be:

- *[What is the correct way to merge upstream without losing changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199286/what-is-the-correct-way-to-merge-upstream-without-losing-changes)*
- *[git: How to fetch from a remote branch and merge into local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196203/git-how-to-fetch-from-a-remote-branch-and-merge-into-local-branch)*
- *[How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git?rq=1)*
- *[Merging between forks in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github)* <- This seemed to have the most potential

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to the answers, I figured this out.
I was not understanding that I needed to push the changes back to the fork:

```
git push origin 4.2.4
```

It appears that what I was trying to do was 'fast forward' my fork. GitHub used to have a fastforward button that would automatically bring your forked repository up to date with the upstream, *[Fast Forward Your Fork](https://github.com/blog/266-fast-forward-your-fork)*. It looks like GitHub got rid of the fast forward feature (as far as I can tell), so I'll have to repeat these steps for every branch.

Comment: +1 for doing your homework. I would give you another +1 for also adding links to the Git repos, but I can only vote once ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just merging the master branch. If you want to follow the upstream branches (I think that is what you want, the inline comment seems to be looking for 4.2.3, etc.) then you need to track them locally (assuming you want the changes available to peruse/edit) and then push them back to your fork.

```
git checkout -t upstream/4.2.3
```

Then push them back to your fork

```
git push origin 4.2.3
```

All fetch is doing is pulling the entire remote. When you `git merge`, your version just merges the upstream/master with your `local/master`.

Comment: Thanks, While this does in theory work as a work around, it is not ideal because I will have to remember to push to my origin every time I commit. If I had write access to both upstream and origin, I could very easily push to the wrong repo.

Comment: You have to specify if you are pushing to somewhere other than origin. If you had write access to upstream, the only way to push there (if you cloned from a fork) is git push upstream <branch>.

Comment: If you really serious about needing to go to the remote only, use the force flag. After fetching from upstream, git push -f origin 4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

`origin` is *your* fork. The upstream repo is called `upstream`, and `upstream/4.2.3`, etc., exist. You can push them to your repository with `$ git push origin upstream/4.2.3`, etc. The two repos will not be synced automatically.

Comment: This sounds good in theory. I've tried it twice, but still don't see 4.2.3 in the origin https://gist.github.com/spudstud/5988534

Comment: @spuder: Did you fetch `origin` after pushing?

Comment: (Granted, I don't think you should have to; I can't remember for sure, though.)